# How to make two graphs together while keep their own properties?

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, dynamic

I have plotted two graphs and I want these two to show together in one graph. But one graph is a rotating ball and the other is simply an arrow.
This is the code:

```
Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], Blue, Arrowheads[0.01], 
Arrow[Tube[{{0, -0.7, -1.5}, {0, -1.7, -2.5}}, 0.003]]}, 
 Boxed -> False, 
 Lighting -> {{"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0., 0.1, 0.01], {1, 0, 0}}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0.605, 0.2, 0.1], {0.5, 0.5, 0}}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0.61, 0.205, 0.1], {0, 1, 0}}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0.615, 0.21, 0.1], {0.5, -0.5, 0}}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0.62, 0.215, 0.1], {0, -1, 0}}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0.625, 0.22, 0.1], {-0.5, -0.5, 0}}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0.63, 0.225, 0.1], {0, -1, 0}}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0.635, 0.23, 0.1], {0.5, -0.5, 0}}}, 
 ViewPoint -> 
  Dynamic[RotationTransform[Clock[{2 \[Pi], 0}, 5], {0, 0, 1}][{1, 0, 
     0}]], PlotRange -> 5, SphericalRegion -> True]
```

I don't want the arrow to rotate. Are there any ways?

Comment: The arrow isn't rotating, the viewpoint is rotating. Either make the sphere rotate, or make the arrow rotate along with the viewpoint. Either way, I'd prefer `Animate[]` over `Dynamic`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gives the impression you wanted

```
Animate[Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], Blue, Arrowheads[0.01], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0, -0.7, -1.5}, {0, -1.7, -2.5}}, 0.003]]}, 
  Boxed -> False, 
  Lighting -> 
   Join[{{"Directional", 
      RGBColor[0., 0.1, 0.01], {Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0}}}, 
    Table[{"Directional", 
      RGBColor[0.6 + 0.005 i, 0.2 + 0.05 i, 
       0.1], {Cos[θ + i π/4], Sin[θ + i π/4], 
       0}}, {i, 7}]]], {θ, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]